# Add multiple elements into flexbox column with jQuery

Tags: jquery, flexbox

I have an array of objects I am iterating through. For each object, I am using jQuery to generate a div (with an attribute from an object) and two buttons.

```
        arrayOfObjects.forEach(object => {
            $('.container').append(`<div>${object.attribute}</div> <button>Default</button> <button>Default</button>`);
        })
```

All of this is housed inside a flexbox container that's to be displayed as wrapped columns (arrangement as columns is important). In other words, I am expecting/want this:

[image: Expected]

Note: I do not want row wrap. Which does what I expect but, once again, arrangement as columns is important:

[image: Not rows]

Instead, I get every element placed on its own column.

[image: Actual]

How can I make it so that it displays as I expected/want? Is it even possible?

This is my current setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .container{
            height: 30vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column wrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        arrayOfObjects.forEach(object => {
            $('.container').append(`<div>${object.attribute}</div> <button>Default</button> <button>Default</button>`);
        })
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line `flex-flow: column wrap;`. Basically, you're displaying the container flex but in a column while you want it to be in a row. Here's how you fix it

```
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

also here's an example: [Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/byegdc5p/)

Comment: I failed to note that order is important. Which is why it must be column wrap. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Np, don't forget that you can [you can accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)